# Failing angular unit test due to dependency injection in angular7?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have `services` depdencies in my `login` component so i placed all dependencies inside  my `login` component's `spec.ts` file like this

```
import { HTTPService, ACLService, HelperService, DataService } from 'app/services';
```

and i am creating `login` component in `.spec` file like this

```
let component: LoginComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
let de: DebugElement;
let el: HTMLElement;
let loginSpy;
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [LoginComponent],
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            LoadingBarHttpClientModule,
            RouterTestingModule,
            SharedModule,
            ToastrModule.forRoot(),
            CookieModule.forRoot(),
            NgxMaskModule.forRoot()
        ],
        providers: [HTTPService, ACLService, HelperService, CookieService, ToastrService, DataService]
    })
        .compileComponents().then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            component.ngOnInit();
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

But still i am getting error of `Dependency Injection` of `DataService` even i added `HelperService` and `DataService` in dependencies.

Here is the error i am getting

[image]

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: That error says `DateService`, not `DataService`...

Comment: ohh right. got it. thanx